# Batch file- Check if %2 exists if not set it to 0

Tags: batch-file, cmd

I am working on a batch file, and I need to check to see if there is a %2 and if there isn't then I need to set %2 to 0

```
    example:
    if "%~2"=="" set "%~2"=0
    example:
    if "%2"=="" set "%2"=0
```

I tried the examples that I posted but, I can't get it to work.

Answer (score 3):

You can't modify or set any parameter (`%2` is one) in batch, you can only modify variables, but that should be no problem.
You can assign the parameter to a variable.

```
set "param2=%~2"
if "%param2%"=="" set "param2=0"
```

Comment: thanks very much, I never thought about setting a variable to a variable.